# Foreach to generate options

Tags: php

Hard to explain literally what I want, but I'll try showing some examples... I need to generate a function for a specific `$_POST`, where this post have the outputs '0' and '1' wich should be 'No' and 'Yes', here's some code to help you guys understand:

```
    private function createTraineeList($treineiro) {
       $row = '';

       foreach ($treineiro as $value) {
          $row .= '<option value="'. $value['training'] .'">'. 'description doesn't have a post' .'</option>';
       }

    return $row;
   }
```

`$treineiro` should be the `$_POST['training']` which returns 0 or 1.

I am using a function to create variables where I can put this specific row into html just calling the name I set into the variable.

The problem is, this code is wrong, and I have no idea how I could use it right, unfortunately I think no one will get what I really need here, but it's worth the try.

EDIT 1: The line 'description doesn't have a post' is not in the code, it was a quote I did because I really don't know what to put in there.

Comment: try using doesn\'t at the place of doesn't

Comment: **...$treineiro should be the $_POST['training'] which returns 0 or 1....**   ***If $treineiro returns a boolean 0 or 1; what is the use of the foreach loop?***  Plus, **You have an unescaped single quote in the word:** ***doesn't*** ...

Comment: Should I use an If statement? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

change here, use escape sequence `\`

```
      $row .= '<option value="'. $value['training'] .'">'. 'description doesn\'t have a post' .'</option>';
```

Also check this to better understand : http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php7p7.html

Comment: The line 'description doesn't have a post' is not in the code, it was a quote I did because I really don't know what to put in there.

Comment: I think after reading the article you will good enough to understand on this :) good luck

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this:

```
    <?php




        private function createTraineeList($treineiro) {
            $row = '';

            // FOREACH MIGHT BE VERY UNNECESSARY SINCE IT IS EITHER 1 OR 0
            // JUST USE A SIMPLE "IF" LIKE SO:
            // AND IF $treineiro IS EITHER 0 OR ONE WHAT IS THE MEANING OF THE $value IN YOUR FOREACH LOOP?
            //foreach ($treineiro as $value) {
            if($treineiro){
                // THE SINGLE QUOTE IN THE "doesn't" NEEDS TO BE ESCAPED.. 
                $row .= '<option name="training" value="'. $treineiro .'">'. 'description doesn\'t have a post' .'</option>';
            }else{
                // I DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU WANT TO DO HERE ....
            }

            return $row;
       }
```

Here is another alternative that assumes that $treineiro is an array with more than one value...

```
        private function createTraineeList($treineiro) {
            $row = '';      
            // THIS ASSUMES THAT THE VARIABLE $treineriro CONTAINS MORE THAN ONE VALUE....
            foreach ($treineiro as $value) {
                $row .= '<option name="training" value="'. $treineiro .'">'. 'description doesn\'t have a post' .'</option>';
            }

            return $row;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I came with a solution, and I'm feeling extremely dumb right now for not thinking about that earlier, but hey, that's the life of a developer, right?

```
 private function createTraineeList() {
    $row = '';

    if (isset($_POST['training'])) {
        if ($_POST['training'] == '0') {
            $row .= '<option value="0" selected="selected">Não</option>
                     <option value="1">Sim</option>';
        } else if ($_POST['training'] == '1') {
            $row .= '<option value="0">Não</option>
                     <option value="1" selected="selected">Sim</option>';
        }

    } else {
        $row .= '<option value="0">Não</option>
                 <option value="1">Sim</option>';
    }

    return $row;
}
```

Feel free to bully me, I deserve it.